# Creating database table error 150

Tags: mysql, create-table

I have this code:

```
 CREATE TABLE `osoby` (
    `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nr_akt` varchar(10),
    `imie1` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    `imie2` varchar(20),
    `nazwisko` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `pesel` int(11),
    `Rel_Stanowisko` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `IsDeleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_Osoby_Stanowisko` FOREIGN KEY (`Rel_Stanowisko`) REFERENCES `stanowisko` (`id_stan`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE `stanowisko` (
    `id_stan` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nazwa_stan` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    `dzial` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    `zakr_wynagr` VARCHAR(10),
    `IsDeleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_stan`)
);

CREATE TABLE `dzial` (
    `id_dzialu` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nazwa_dzialu` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    `skr_nazwa_dzialu` VARCHAR(10),
    `IsDeleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_dzialu`)
);

CREATE TABLE pracownik (
    `id_prac` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_osoby` int(6) NOT NULL,
    `id_stan` int(4),
    `id_dzialu` int(4),
    `pensja` int(4),
    `IsDeleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_prac`)
);
```

I know that the problem is with foreign key but I don't know how to resolve this
And I have this error:

```
13:24:17    CREATE TABLE `osoby` ( `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `nr_akt` varchar(10), `imie1` varchar(20) NOT NULL, `imie2` varchar(20), `nazwisko` varchar(50) NOT NULL, `pesel` int(11), `Rel_Stanowisko` int(11) NOT NULL, `IsDeleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', PRIMARY KEY (`Id`), CONSTRAINT `fk_Osoby_Stanowisko` FOREIGN KEY (`Rel_Stanowisko`) REFERENCES `stanowisko` (`id_stan`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION )   Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'hurtownia.osoby' (errno: 150) 0.327 sec
```

I can't create table because I have error number 150.
Anyone see where i have problem?

Comment: create first stanowisko table then osoby

Comment: First create that table which have primary key then create foreign key refresh table. in your case you are first foreign key table then primary key table.....

Answer (score 0):

Your first table is having dependency on the second table. So first create second table then first table or change the order as below :

```
CREATE TABLE stanowisko ( id_stan int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, nazwa_stan VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, dzial VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, zakr_wynagr VARCHAR(10), IsDeleted tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', PRIMARY KEY (id_stan) );

CREATE TABLE osoby ( Id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, nr_akt varchar(10), imie1 varchar(20) NOT NULL, imie2 varchar(20), nazwisko varchar(50) NOT NULL, pesel int(11), Rel_Stanowisko int(11) NOT NULL, IsDeleted tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', PRIMARY KEY (Id), CONSTRAINT fk_Osoby_Stanowisko FOREIGN KEY (Rel_Stanowisko) REFERENCES stanowisko (id_stan) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION );

CREATE TABLE dzial ( id_dzialu int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, nazwa_dzialu VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, skr_nazwa_dzialu VARCHAR(10), IsDeleted tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', PRIMARY KEY (id_dzialu) );

CREATE TABLE pracownik ( id_prac int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, id_osoby int(6) NOT NULL, id_stan int(4), id_dzialu int(4), pensja int(4), IsDeleted tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', PRIMARY KEY (id_prac) );
```